# Create multiple untagged virtual interface on a single physical interface

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, vlan

For some very specific reason, I need to create 4 virtual interfaces with different MAC address on each virtual interface, the frames from those interfaces will needs be sent over a **single** physical interface **without any VLAN tags** (the device on other ends will look at my PC and thinks my PC is a dumb switch because frames from different MAC address is being sent towards them)

I've tried this command `ip link add link eth0 name untagged type vlan id 0` which managed to create an untagged virtual interface but when I tried to create another one and replace the `0` then it said `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`

Again, I'm not trying to create a trunk over the physical interface, a tagged frame being sent out the physical interface is not suitable for my purpose because the other end doesn't understand a VLAN tagged frame or a trunk interface for that matter.

How I could accomplish this?

Comment: Try a "macvlan", which you can see in `man ip-link`

Comment: Nice, that works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to LL3 I found out that this feature is called `macvlan`, for your reference I'll put the command here:

```
ip link add link eth0 address 00:cc:cc:cc:11:33 eth0mac2 type macvlan
ip link set eth0mac2 up
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/576337/macvlan-interface-and-ppp-session

This can be used to create a L2 virtual interface for PPPoE